# Raid 0 - Secure format

Tags: hard-drive, raid

I am getting ready to sell a Lacie Big 5 20tb drive and I wanted to make sure my files were gone securely before mailing.

I formated the raid-0, then destroyed it, created a new raid, formatted again, then repeated that one more time.

After that I proceeded to transfer about 1TB of garbage data, (which is about how much data I had stored of my own files) I then once more, formatted, destroyed, and recreated the RAID 0.

My question is would file recovery programs be able to piece together any data in terms of smaller files like pictures, or larger files like ISO images.

I just dont have the time to do the writing 1's to the drive multiple times as it said it will take 30 something hours per pass.

I am more interested as I see lots of people talking about hardware failure Raid0 being gone for good, and not necessarily formated drives

Thanks a lot,

Anthony

Comment: Zero fill all the drives to destroy all the data. Formatting does not destroy data.

Comment: @Moab but wont writing garbage data around the same size of my previously stored data take care of this. It was in JHFS+ on a mac.

Comment: No, it will not write it to the same place on the disk. I resell hard drives and zero fill is all I use, no way to recover data using this method.

Comment: @Moab, supposedly the gov't or other sufficiently advanced entities can disassemble the drive and still recover data after it has been overwritten a few times, thus they recommend overwriting it with random data several times if you are sufficiently paranoid.  Short of dismantling the drive and using things like scanning electron microscopes on the platters though, for the "regular" variety of paranoid, overwriting the entire drive once is enough.

Comment: To clarify what @Moab was saying, simply writing over the first 1tb of the drive does not erase data stored beyond that point on the drive, and it is quite likely that even if you only had 1tb of files on the drive, some of them were stored beyond that point.  If the data in question really is that significant ( like banking information ) then you need to use something like `hdparm --secure-erase` on the drive, which will rather securely insure everything on the drive is gone, but also is faster than other methods of overwriting the drive.

Comment: @psusi I just want enough that a simple file recovery program wont pick anything up, I have work files and what not and some family photos I don't want random people having.
But I don't need to go DOJ of 7 passes, I just want someone to have to work to get some files.

Comment: @psusi that is a rumor and has never been proven. No one has ever proven to recover data that has been overwritten one time.

Comment: @Moab, that's why I said *supposedly* and then once is enough.

Comment: Easier methods then writing random data, encrypt the entire space, including all free space.  This encrypts everything that might or might not be recoverable then forget the password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite possible that the data could be recovered.  Formatting a disk only wipes the metadata area; the data is entirely untouched.  Writing data to part of the drive may not over-write the area containing the data you're trying to destroy.  Creating and deleting a RAID array may not touch the contents of the disks at all.

If you want reasonable certainty that your data is gone while minimizing the time needed, create a RAID-1 array, fill it *completely* with garbage data, then delete the data.  Filling the drive forces it to over-write the area containing the data you're trying to destroy, while doing it on a RAID-1 array lets you write to two disks for the effort of one.

The 35-pass [Gutmann wipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gutmann_method) is designed to cover all possible drive technologies from the early 1980s on, and protect against three-letter-agency-level attackers.  If you're concerned about ordinary data-recovery companies, or are using a drive manufactured since the late 1990s, you only need one of those passes: a single write with random data, although an all-zeroes or all-ones write will probably do equally well.